# how to "use unicode character set" in g++?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, g++, cl

i'm working on a program in c++ where i'm trying to use the WriteProcessMemory() function in windows. for that i need a function that gets the target process id. i'm able to do that using the following function:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>

//get process id from executable name using tlhelp32snapshot
DWORD GetProcID(wchar_t *exeName){
    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry = {0};
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (!hSnapshot) {
        return 0;
    }
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);
    if (!Process32First(hSnapshot, &procEntry)) {
        return 0;
    }
    do {
        if (!wcscmp(procEntry.szExeFile, exeName)) {
            CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
            return procEntry.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &procEntry));
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    return 0;
}

//main function
int main() {
    using namespace std;

    cout << "some output" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

i'm able to compile using visual studio if i set the character set to unicode but when i try using g++ i get a conversion error:

```
g++ -std=c++17 write.cpp
write.cpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
 #pragma once
         ^
write.cpp: In function 'DWORD GetProcID(wchar_t*)':
write.cpp:21:43: error: cannot convert 'CHAR* {aka char*}' to 'const wchar_t*' for argument '1' to 'int wcscmp(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
   if (!wcscmp(procEntry.szExeFile, exeName)) {
                                           ^
write.cpp: In function 'MODULEENTRY32 GetModule(DWORD, wchar_t*)':
write.cpp:40:46: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'const wchar_t*' for argument '1' to 'int wcscmp(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
     if (!wcscmp(modEntry.szModule, moduleName)) {
                                              ^
```

i'm able to compile with cl using the arguments:

```
cl /EHsc /D UNICODE write.cpp
```

here `/D UNICODE` is the same as going in visual studio > rmb on project > properties and seting `Character Set` to `Use Unicode Character Set`.

is there an option to force unicode in g++ like in cl?

Comment: Yes, g++ has `-DUNICODE` parameter. Or you can `#define UNICODE` directly in your code. (and I would remove the `#pragma once`, it's not a header)

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. i used `#define UNICODE` prior and it didn't work, so i took it out, but i tried `-DUNICODE` and it actually worked. thanks a lot.

Comment: You should use `W` stuff: `PROCESSENTRY32W` and so on. Also this function mya leak resources if returns at first return statement.

Comment: Use `-municode` switch (assuming you're using mingw-w64), as well as defining UNICODE it also links the right version of main and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cl` (Microsoft C/C++ Compiler) and `g++` (Gnu C++ Compiler) have a very close arguments syntax on certain parameter. The delta is more of the usual difference Dos / Shell (slash vs dash).

The equivalent of `/DMY_IDENTIFIER` (`cl`) is on `g++`:

```
-DMY_IDENTIFER
```

Which means in your case: `-DUNICODE`

The complete compilation command line would have to look like:

```
g++ -DUNICODE -std=c++17 write.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer here is to use the compiler switch `-municode` which defines everything you need, and links to the correct CRT files as to provide you with the proper definition of `_wmain`.

This is not available on ye olde MinGW, so you'll need a MinGW-w64 toolchain for that. Chances are you are already using that anyway. If that is not the case, you can download the installer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download).

Comment: You opended my eyes on something I really missed up related to compilers. Now, I will always look if a `-m`option exists for what I'm doing.